# Is it wrong to use a pronoun object \ comparison

Tags: grammaticality

****The author said, "it is wrong grammar using the objective pronoun.
On the other hand, I see people everywhere use it as well as many other authors  ?**** So, with whom or which we go ?

I am not a native speaker, and I may ask:

**Is not there any standard rules in English ?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it not a clear  question ?  How can I clear it more ?     The author said, "it is wrong grammar using the objective pronoun. On the other hand, I see people everywhere use it as well as many other authors  ?